# pyspark dataframe column value replace with index in another list in pyspark version 2.3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-2.3

I have a pyspark  dataframe with column values as a list .I need to replace the values in the list with index based on another python list

```
outer_list = [b,c,a,e,f,d]
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             USER_ID|            OFFERIDS|
+--------------------+--------------------+
| X                  + [a,b,c]            | 
+--------------------+--------------------+
| Y                  + [d,e,f]            |
+--------------------+--------------------+

+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|             USER_ID|            OFFERIDS|             INDEXED|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+          
| X                  + [a,b,c]            |        [2,0,1]     |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+ 
| Y                  + [d,e,f]            |        [5,3,4]     |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Creating a udf in pyspark didnot work

```
replace_index = udf(lambda x:  [outer_list.index(offer) for offer in x if offer in outer_list ], ArrayType(IntegerType()) )
```

Can anyone help me where am I going wrong

```
userid_offerid_index = df.withColumn('INDEXED_OFFERIDS', replace_index('OFFERIDS'))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 186, in wrapper
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 164, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 148, in _judf
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 157, in _create_judf
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 33, in _wrap_function
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2391, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 575, in dumps
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 918, in dumps
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 249, in dump
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o69.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Where is defined `outer_list`? maybe in another object or class?

Comment: attribute in the same class

Comment: No, when you reference `self.outer_list` inside the UDF the class (`self`) needs to be serialized but it fails, thus you get the error msg: `Could not serialize object`. You can define the list directly in the UDF or pass it as a literal parameter to your UDF.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot . removed the outer_list as class attribute and assigned to local variable. That worked. I have been struggling from past one day. Thanks